# Horizontally scale an object (row, document) comprised entirely of lists

Tags: nosql, sharding, listfield, horizontal-scaling

Have some data that looks like this:

```
widget:
{
    categories: ['hair', 'nails', 'dress']
    colors:     ['red', 'white']
}
```

The data needs to be queried like this:

```
SELECT * FROM widget_table WHERE categories == 'hair' AND colors == 'red'
```

In this case the equality operator `categories == 'hair'` is really saying `WHERE 'hair' equals at least one of the values in the list`. Using an algorithm that I believe to be called a 'zigzag merge join', this operation can be done much the same Big O time as a traditional equality operation.

The data set that we are working with contains on the order of tens of millions of these objects. The query provided above needs to be executed against the database about 50 times per second. There are also roughly 50 insertions per second against this database. Because of this requirement, the database must be scaled horizontally across multiple machines in such a way that read and write operations do not have to hit all of the machines in the cluster. I believe the best way to do this is to use `sharding`.

As I understand it, as long as a query does not include a non-equality operator against more than one field, the data that it queries can be indexed and sharded across multiple machines. (This was the rule for GAE's Big Table)

I was under the impression that MongoDB would be a good candidate for this use case, however I recently became aware to one caveat of MongoDB's sharding capability: a list field can not be used as a shard key. Therefore, if I wanted to use MongoDB for this, I would have to write a hack in the data layer of the application connecting to MongoDB. This is a question I posted previously regarding storing and querying for this use case using MongoDB: [Can a list field be a shard key in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408544/can-a-list-field-be-a-shard-key-in-mongodb)

I have previously implemented these requirements using GAE's Big Table, which as I understand it, is a database sharded on a massive scale. However, due to GAE's high costs for accessing big table (about $1 for 1 million read or write operations?), we have since moved our infrastructure to cloud servers (we are on Rackspace cloud servers now, if you are unfamiliar with them, they are similar to Amazon EC2).

### My question is:

**What database should we be using for this?**

I know there are other NoSQL databases out there that claim to be able be able to scale horizontally like CouchDB and Cassandra. And I thought that MongoDB was one of them. I feel a little incompetent that we've spent a few weeks porting a lot of our data into MongoDB and then find out that it does not support one of our major use cases. Would like to not make this mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

With anything non-relational (NoSQL), you must match the data structure with the type of database, or it will break your project.

MongoDB is awesome, but it's best at querying the semi-structured data within "documents"  Not across collections.   In other words DocumentDB's are about queries that avoid JOIN, with MongoDB you *can* do non-idiomatic queries, but they won't scale.... as you experienced.  Again, love MongoDB, but I don’t think it fits your use case.

In your situation,
especially since you said BigTable was a solid fit for your type of queries/data structure. I would recommend you investigate a few Column-oriented Databases.  Cassandra would be worth checking out for sure.